# PyCharm Code Completion on function parameters

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm

I have written a function in python that expects a parameter (message) of a special class "Message" from a library. Unfortunately i dont get recommendations for autocompletion when i write message. and press strg + space in the function's body because PyCharm doesnt know its an object of the class Message. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: It's not super clear, but it kind of sounds like you want type hints. Like `def function(msg: Message):`; where `Message` is your message class. That will allow autocompletion inside of the function. Please show a [mcve] of the case you're looking at though for better suggestions.

Comment: this was the solution, thank you!

Comment: I'll note that if you really want to get into it, the link Kosaaaa posted is a good, but the definitive reference is [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). There's a few more additions to it in later PEPs, but that's the meat of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using type definition https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

something like this

```py
class Message:
    pass

def foo(message: Message):
    print(message)
```